# Replace wild characters with `\` + wild charcter in R with gsub

Tags: regex, r

I want to replace the wild characters with the same character but with `\` prefix.

For example:

```
gsub("#","\\#","234254#3")
```

Expected result: `234254\#3`
but we get:

```
  "234254#3"



   gsub(" ","\\ ","234254 3")
```

Expected result: `234254\ 3`

but we get:

```
"234254 3"
```

But this commands does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `fixed=TRUE` as 4th parameter of `gsub` and use `\\` in replacement:

```
res <- gsub("#", "\\#", "234254#3", fixed=TRUE)
cat(res)
```

**Output:**

```
234254\#3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
 res <- gsub("#","\\\\#","234254#3")
 cat(res, '\n')
 #234254\#3 
 nchar(res)
 #[1] 9
```

To make it more clear

```
 nchar('\\')
 #[1] 1
```

For the second one also, it is the same `\\\\`

```
 gsub(" ","\\\\ ","234254 3")
```

Comment: I get ` "234254\\#3"`! Double backslash.

Comment: @user1436187 If you print it with `cat` it is just a single `\`.  It is for escaping the escape character

Comment: @user1436187  How is the other answer different in terms of the output?